# iPhone GPS (location) API link required

Tags: api, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am new to iPhone Application... I want to use GPS API in my iPhone Application, for getting current location of iPhone.. Can any one plz post some links for GPS API for iPhone ? Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at Core Location framework: [Apple link here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/Frameworks/CoreServices/CoreLocation/)

Link is not valid anymore, please see Heiko Behrens's post.

Comment: It's not so hard to scroll down one post ;) And I don't want to steal his rating.

Answer (score 7):

The link from ttvd is not valid anymore. They the current [link to the documentation of CoreLocation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/) instead